# How to subnet a network into subnets of varying sizes?

Tags: algorithm, networking, ip, subnet

I have a network `193.219.64.0/24`, and I need to cut `193.219.64.24/30` from it.
So now I have an subnet in the middle of network. What steps I should consider, while subneting rest of the given network, for maximum use of adresses?

I was studing this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WzH8uVG11WY), but there isn't case where you have the minimum size subnet in the middle. What is more, I don't know what subnets will be on demand from the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can start with :

since our network mask is /24 we have 0-255 IP range , and we want 192.219.64.24/30 too, so insted from starting like 192.219.64.0/25 we can start with 192.219.64.128/25 and proceed ..

193.219.64.128 /25
--> 192.219.64.255  (will give 128 address)

193.219.64.64 /26
--> 192.219.64.127  (will give 64 address)

193.219.64.32 /27
--> 192.219.64.63  (will give 32 address)

193.219.64.24 /30
--> 192.219.64.27  (will give 4 address) desired one.. and so on...